# Сравнение timeStamp'ов

Tags: java, дата, timestamp

У меня есть дата, которая представлена строкой. Эта дата в будущем, для примера я взял сегодняшнюю дату + несколько часов вперед от текущего момента после чего я создаю timestamp указаной даты и timestamp такущего момента после чего  их сравниваю. Проблема заключается в том что timestamp текущего момента получается больше чем даты в будущем,в чем может быть проблема?

```
String estimatedEndDate = "2017-07-22 19:00";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm");
Date date = null;

try {
    date = dateFormat.parse(estimatedEndDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

long time = date.getTime();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(time);
Timestamp current = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

if (current.compareTo(timestamp) == 1) {
    log.warning("time left");
}
```

Comment: У вас минуты и месяцы парсятся одинаковыми обозначениями

Comment: да, это и было ошибкой, уже исправил, спасибо!

Comment: @etki можете опубликовать ответ, если хотите!